# Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Could not delete caches dir yourProject\build\kotlin\compileDebugTestingKotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Sometimes this unexpected message appear and the only way to deal with this is to restart the pc and when it starts again go to the obove path and delete the file before start Android Studio with the project. It works for some time but latter appears again. Maybe someone of you know how deal better with this annoying  issue.

```
CreateProcess error=206, El nombre del archivo o la extensión es demasiado largo
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Could not delete caches dir YourProjectPath\build\kotlin\compileDebugTestingKotlin
```

Comment: Jetbrains Kotlin issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-36253

Answer (score 43):

In windows open task manager.

- **Go to details tab.**
- **Look for Java.exe.**
- **End Task for all instances of Java.exe.**

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: For me it was enough to kill just one of two Java.exe that takes less memory. In that case Gradle daemon won't be killed.

Comment: every time to open task manager , and then kill java.exe , it's too troublesome!!

Comment: Yea, that's right but I could not find a better way to fix the problem. Also, I found this problem in some big projects. Small projects are ok.

Comment: By this, the problem is getting solved but every run needs to kill java.exe.

Comment: I think this is the fastest solution but would love to know the cause. It does not like something about my projects because this is coming up often since updating to 4.1.X

Comment: How to get rid of it, I am getting this every time.

Comment: Same here too how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 27):

Notice: This happens with the newer AndroidStudio **4.2.x**.

### Temporary solution:

Delete (the contents of) the folder which is giving you the issue. For example:

```
..\app\build\kotlin\compileDebugKotlin\caches-jvm\inputs
```

If you get: "The file is open in OpenJDK Platform Binary" you'll need to stop these processes through `Windows Task Manager > Details > Java.exe`.

*Please know that with this method the error will repeat again after several assembly attempts.*

### UPDATE:

Google hasn't provide us a fix, so you'll need to [downgrade](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) to an older version which works for you. 4.1.3 seems to be working fine.

Comment: I updated Android Studio 4.2 too, and I have same problem. really annoying.

Comment: ok, I downgrade AS version to 4.1.3, too. It worked.

Comment: 4.2 has so many problems. Do not even think about upgrading. I lost 6-7 my workdays.

Comment: @bongtoi how do you downgrade  ur android studio ?

Comment: @AhsanSyed current AS version (4.2) still available. You need to download additional an old AS version (4.1.3) at [Archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive). It mean you have 2 AS version at the same time.

Comment: But downgrading is not the actual solution, is there any alternate solution to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

In windows open task manager `CTRL` + `ALT` + `DEL`
You can see java.exe on the details page.
End Task for all instances of Java.exe

[image]

Answer (score 6):

in windows

run the below command in the terminal android studio:

```
taskkill /f /im java.exe
```

and run again.

[image: terminal android studio]

Answer (score 0):

invalidating cache and restarting worked for me

Answer (score 0):

uninstall application from mobile and run it again it works

Answer (score -1):

Try reopening Android Studio and clean your project. Worked for my cache issue.

Comment: No, it's not the cache issue

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Android Studio version Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 and I got the same error. In order to fix it, we need to kill the process `Java.exe`

Comment: What's the difference between your answer Vs the above answers?

Answer (score -1):

ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

update all version

Comment: No, didn't worked

Answer (score -2):

Updating project level `build.gradle` from:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
```

solved my issue.
If it won't fix yours you can also try to update:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: in my case, it worked well and I also tried my friend's machines it helps to get rid of the problem