# Error running the app in Android Studio Arctic Fox with version 2020.3.1 patch 3

Tags: android-studio

I am getting this error always when I try to run the app from the android studio Arctic Fox with version 2020.3.1 patch 3.

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Could not delete caches dir D:\Username\path\to\project\app\build\kotlin\compileDemoDebugKotlin
```

When I kill the Java processes running in the Task Manager then it is working for some time then again getting the same issue next time.

About:
[image]

Anyone facing a similar issue? what could be the solution to fix it?

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832868/caused-by-java-lang-assertionerror-could-not-delete-caches-dir-yourproject-bui

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in my question it's working fine when I kill java processes. But I am looking for a permanent solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Could not delete caches dir yourProject\build\kotlin\compileDebugTestingKotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832868/caused-by-java-lang-assertionerror-could-not-delete-caches-dir-yourproject-bui)

Comment: File-system permission issues are not really programming related, despite an IDE complained.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but have not found a complete solution other than downgrading the Android Studio.

Comment: In the link I sent the second answer says you should try to downgrade gradle to 4.1.3, have you tried that?

Comment: I don't want to do that, just want is there any better solution?